# Laravel 5.7: prevent auto load injection in controller constructor

Tags: laravel-5

I have a `HomeController` with his constructor that takes a Guzzle instance.

```
   /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param \GuzzleHttp\Client|null $client
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client = null)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('user.settings');
        if ($client === null) {
            $param = [
                'base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org/',
                'defaults' => [
                    'exceptions' => false,
                    'verify' => false
                ]
            ];
            $client = new Client($param);
        }
        $this->setClient($client);
    }
```

I would use via __constructor() to be able to mock it in tests.
My issues is that Laravel automatically auto-load the injection and the Guzzle Client injected has blank defaults (and cannot anymore edit it). In other words: at first call of HomeController `Client` is not null. And I need as null.

How can I stop this behaviour (only for the __construct() for HomeController)? I really use the DI in every part of my webapp.

EDIT

I just find that if I don't type-hints the `Client`, of course Laravel cannot auto-load. Is this the right mode to work?

New constructor:

`public function __construct($client = null)`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular situation when testing apis. I ended up binding an instance of GuzzleClient to the service container (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#basic-usage)). Something like:

```
$this->app->instance('GuzzleHttp\Client', new MockClient);
```

To successfully mock the instance, I then checked to see whether or not it had a certain property value (in my case `base_url` being set). That determined whether or not the instance was a test as `base_url` would be set.

Along side this method, `GuzzleHttp\Client` does have a [MockHandler](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html) you may want to explore. This can be used to fake response bodies, headers and status codes.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of MockHandler (and I use it). Btw I think I did found my solution: simply not typehinting ends with no-auto resolve from Laravel...

Comment: @sineverba That would help. What I ended up doing was creating a new class which replaced the Guzzle DI. I had good reason as I was using a wrapper class, that helped me to just swap out the instance on load. Also cleaned up the construct.